# Upload Video to S3 bucket using Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, amazon-s3, ionic-framework

I have used `cordova-plugin-camera` to access media from Photo Library for images it works fine as I receive `DATA_URL`.

But for videos I receive `FILE_URI` (as per the documentation). If I assign the URI to an HTML5 video source it works fine, but what I want is to upload it to Amazon S3 bucket, so I need to convert that file into a blob. When I try to do that it throws an exception:

> TypeError: Failed to execute readasdataurl on FileReader parameter